# When and why was the ark placed at the front of the shul?

Tags: synagogue, ark-aron-kodesh

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torah_ark#Placement) states that:

> In some ancient synagogues, such as the fifth-century synagogue in
>   Susia, the Torah scroll was not placed inside the synagogue at all,
>   but in a room adjacent to it, signifying that the sacredness of the
>   synagogue does not come from the ark but from its being a house of
>   prayer. The Torah was brought into the synagogue for reading purposes.

I'm not sure if the majority of the first synagogues followed this idea and had the ark separate from the main prayer area. But, I haven't seen any shul that does not have the Aron Kodesh within the shul, itself. So, something changed at some point for some reason. When did that happen, and why was that change made?

Comment: Don't you think it might be disrespectful to turn your back to the aron kodesh, where the sifrei Torah are kept?

Comment: A source for your last statement would be great

Comment: " Why did the rule / halacha then become to face the Aron?"
It did not. The aron is placed based on the way we face

Comment: Thanks to everyone who commented. It helped me revise my question. Please delete irrelevant comments, in view of the above edits.